# Exportar excel a php

Tags: php, mysql, excel

buenas tardes

Estuve probando realizar una pagina para poder exportar datos de manera masiva a la BD con un excel
Probe varias librerias y no tuve caso
Termine probando unos tutoriales de YT y siempre me pasa lo mismo en esta parte.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando ejecuto, me dice que no tengo la extension ZIP habilitada en PHP.ini y la habilite previamente
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La version que estoy utilizando de PhpSpreadsheet es la 1.18.0

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Perdon y muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola, puedes hacer el [tour] para entender como funciona Stackoverflow y el apartado [ask] para tener las pautas necesarias para que tu pregunta capte la atención y sea respondida. También proporciona un [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has hecho o errores que tienes y fundamentalmente parte del código que has utilizado (en texto, no imagen).

Comment: Reiniciaste el servidor después de habilitar la extensión zip?

Comment: Buen dia Ochoa, si el motivo por el que subi el codigo asi fue porque fue la unica manera, probe de insertar codigo y la pagina no me dejaba subirlo

Comment: DjCrazy, muchas gracias